# How to use template data type inside main function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, typing

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class U>
U add (U a, U b)
{
    U c = 0 ;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int first = 2;
    int second = 2;

    U result = 0;

    result = add(first, second);

    cout <<  result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to declare the data type of result variable using the template data type so that my addition program is generic but the compiler is giving me this error "result was not declared in this scope."

Comment: `U` is a teplate parameter. It's local to the template function and makes no sense outside of it. What do you expect to get from `U result = 0;`? What type do you want `U` to become in this line? You should replace that line with `int result = 0`.

Comment: I want store the result returned by function in this variable. If the function returns double the type of this variable should become double and if it returns int the type of result variable should become int. Is it possible ?

Comment: Reasonably question but the title needs some work. I can't think of a good replacement right now though.

Comment: @AbdulMoizFarooq Then use Jose's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. You can only use U within your add function.

However, you can do this instead

```
auto result = add(first, second);
```

Or

```
decltype(auto) result = add(first, second);
```

In your case both will do the same. However, they are quite different. To make it short, `decltype(auto)` will always get you the exact type returned by `add`, while `auto` may not.

Quick example:

```
const int& test()
{
    static int c = 0;
    return c;
}

// result type: int
auto result = test();

// result type: const int&
decltype(auto) result = test();
```

If you want to know more about auto, Scott Meyers explains it perfectly:

[CppCon 2014: Scott Meyers "Type Deduction and Why You Care"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to José's excellent proposal, which would allow you to split the declaration and "initialisation" (which would then only be an assignment, as in your question), is:

```
decltype(add(first, second)) result = 0;
result = add(first, second);
```

But, obviously, yuck.